# vue.js: uppercase tagname for filter not recognized

Tags: svg, vue.js

I am trying out vue.js to use form inputs to change a svg-element, for example the position and some filter-value of some rect.

Below is part of an example, using two range inputs. See also https://jsfiddle.net/tyk4Ltkg/
The position is not giving any problem: the y coordinate (ypos) of the rect example is correctly updated after changing the input slider.

However, the blur-filter is not responding. Although the number gets updates from the input range to the dom-element, the tag seems to be converted to lowercases (stddeviation), after which my browser (chrome) seems to ignore it.

How can I fix this ? Thanks!

```
<div id='app'>
    <input type='range' v-model='stdev'>
    <input type='range' v-model='ypos'>

    <svg id="#mymainsvg">
        <defs>
            <filter id='mymainfilter'>
                <feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' :stdDeviation=stdev ></feGaussianBlur>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <rect :y=ypos width=100 height=100 style="filter:url(#mymainfilter)"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            ypos: 5,
            stdev: 13               
        }
    });       
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<feGaussianBlur in='SourceGraphic' stdDeviation='{{stdev}}'></feGaussianBlur>`

Since it isn't a Vue prop you don't use :stdDeviation.  Instead, just use the moustaches to tell Vue to evaluate the expression.